# Probability distribution for angle between two vectors

Tags: random-variables

I got used to treat transformation of random variables in the following way. Example: let $x, y \sim P_{\{x,y\}} (x, y)$. Then if $z = f(x, y)$, the probability distribution for $z$ would be*

$$
P_z (z) = \int P (x, y) \, \delta (z - f (x, y))
$$

So I have a following problem: I have a distribution $P (r)$ for magnitudes of vector $\vec{r}$ and also $P_\theta (\theta)$ for the angle between $\vec{r}$ and $\hat{z}$, i.e. $\cos \theta = z / r$ and $r$ and $\theta$ are *uncorrelated*. If this is true, then $z = r \cos \theta$ and the PDF for $z$-component only is

$$
P_z (z) = \int \limits_0^\infty \mathrm{d} r \, P_r (r) \int \limits_0^\pi \mathrm{d} \theta \, P_\theta (\theta) \, \delta (z - r \cos \theta)
$$

This can be simplified further by letting $u = \cos \theta$ and integrating over $\theta$ using the $\delta$-function, but that's not important now. In this integral, everything is clear to me.

However, when I try to invert this logic and get the distribution for $\theta$ from knowing distributions for $z$ and $r$, I run into problems. Naively, the formula is as follows

$$
P_\theta (\theta) = \int \limits_0^\infty \mathrm{d} r \, P_r (r) \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d} z \, P_z(z) \, \delta (\theta - \cos^{-1} (z/r))
$$

Problem: the argument of the $\delta$-function is complex for $z > r$. That makes sense: in everyday geometry, $|z| < r$, because no component can be bigger than the magnitude of the vector, however, statistically, there is nothing that would prevent to have $|z| > r$ in this integral: in fact, if $P_r (r)$ doesn't have a sharp cutoff, $P_z (z)$ extends to infinity as well (can be seen from the expression for $P_z (z)$ above).

**So where is the catch in all this? Am I supposed to just restrict the integral over $z$ between $-B$ and $B$ so that the expression inside the $\delta$-function is real only? Or, there might be a mistake in my assumptions: while $r$ and $\theta$ can be statistically independent (as it happens in isotropic systems), $r$ and $z$ are always correlated, so $P (r, z)$ cannot be separated and must be treated together, thus $|z| < r$ would be true by the nature of the function of $P (r, z)$ (it would be zero if $|z| > r$)? If this is true, how is the joint distribution for $r$ and $z$ obtained, given the distributions for $r$ and $\theta$ (uncorrelated)?**

*Derivation: the CDF for $z$ is given by
$$
F_z (z) = \int P (x, y) \, \theta(f (x, y) - z)
$$
because of the simple counting: $\theta$-function chooses the part of the $x,y$ space that satisfies $z < f (x, y)$. The formula for the PDF is obtained by differentiating w.r.t. $z$

Comment: Where you write "uncorrelated", I think you mean "independent". Variables can be (linearly) uncorrelated yet dependent; see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence).

Comment: Yes, absolutely! I forgot what the name is, what I mean is f (x, y) = f_x (x) f_y (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second suggestion (the one that begins with "Or") is correct. The joint distribution $P_{r,z}(r,z)$ is obtained from

$$
P_{r,z}(r,z)\mathrm dr\mathrm dz=P_{r,\theta}(r,\theta)\mathrm dr\mathrm d\theta
$$

as

$$
P_{r,z}(r,z)=P_{r,\theta}(r,\theta)\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm dz}=P_r(r)P_\theta(\theta)\frac1{\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}\;.
$$

Comment: The last part of the equation, in the argument of P_theta, is theta = arccos(z/r)? Now it makes sense and it shows explicitly why r, z must be dependent.

Comment: @user16320: Exactly.